# How to map a list of objects on another one with condition

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists. One of them has an Id

```
var a = new List<MyModel>
            {
                new MyModel()
                {
                    id = 1,
                    prop1 = 1,
                    prop2 = 1
                },
                new MyModel()
                {
                    id = 2,
                    prop1 = 2,
                    prop2 = 3
                },
            };
```

and another one hasn't, but they are identical on combination of `prop1` and `prop2`

```
var b = new List<MyModel>
            {
                new MyModel()
                {
                    prop1 = 1,
                    prop2 = 1
                },
                new MyModel()
                {
                    prop1 = 2,
                    prop2 = 3
                },
            };
```

I need to populate list `b` with ids from list `a` when `a.prop1 = b.prop1 && a.prop2 == b.prop2` but I don't know how to write this linq properly

The two list are always identical, but unordered. I think I can sort them and just assign them one by one, but I wonder if there another way

Comment: do you have a working solution using a loop? what should happen with the Id if it does not match ? Is the order in the 2 lists the same? are they of equal length? can there be multiple matches?

Comment: LINQ is a *query* language, so it not intended to be used for *changing* data. So if you want to assign `id`s on matching items, then you probably may want to use ordinary loop instead of LINQ. But you still can use LINQ to query matched items with corresponding ids.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that the lists are identical, there's just one missing IDs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
var query =
    from bb in b
    join aa in a on new { bb.prop1, bb.prop2 } equals new { aa.prop1, aa.prop2 }
    select new { bb, aa.id };
    
foreach (var q in query)
    q.bb.id = q.id;
```

Comment: Nice solution man